# Should I make sure to destroy SDL 2.0 objects (renderer, window, textures, etc.) before exiting the program?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

[This](http://twinklebeardev.blogspot.com/2012/07/lesson-2-dont-put-everything-in-main.html) tutorial on SDL 2.0 uses code that returns from main without first destroying any of the resource pointers:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == -1){
        std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1; 
    }

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Lesson 2", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (window == nullptr){
        std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 2; //this
    }
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED 
        | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    if (renderer == nullptr){
        std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 3; //and this too
    }
```

Should I tell my terminate function to DestroyRenderer, DestroyWindow, DestroyTexture, etc. before exiting?

Answer (score 2):

Same question as 'should i free memory that i've allocated before quitting a program'. Yes, if there is no bugs in SDL/X11/GL/etc. finalize code - all will be freed anyway. But i see no reasons why you shouldn't want to do that yourself.

Of course if you crash rather then exit - there is a good chance some things wouldn't be done and e.g. you wouldn't return display to native desktop resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Ive personally had problems with SDL_TEXTURE that caused a memory leak while the program was running and the display of pictures just stopped after the program leaked about 2gb of ram when normally it uses 37 mb of ram.

```
SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
```

Just called this afer every time i used to display a different picture with renderer and the memory leak was gone

Comment: The question asks about destroying stuff right "before exiting the program", not while it's running.

Comment: What i ment by my answer was that the program never reached before exit state at all because of the SDL_DestroyTexture abscense